# laravel 4 diferences between getting object property

Tags: object, laravel, laravel-4

I really wonder that when to get property of an object in laravel are there any differences between examples below:

```
$user->name
```

and

```
$user['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

`$user->name` uses `__get()` magic method, `$user['name']` uses `offsetGet()` that is implemented for conformity to ArrayAccess interface that also calls `$user->name`, so both end up calling the same method, `__get($key)`.

Comment: alright, and when it comes to speed it produce any difference between them?

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about that, I'm sure the speed difference is negligible.